# Gamma correction implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gamma

I'm trying to do a gamma correction function in MATLAB, and to say the least, I'm getting some mixed results. Where using a gamma constant below 1 (such as 0.5) gives me a brighter image, and using a constant above 1 gives me a darker image, which is wrong since it should give me opposite results (constant lower than 1 should be darker and constant higher than 1 should be brighter).

Here's the code I've been working on based on the following formula that I found while looking at an image processing book:

> f(v):= 255·(v/255) 1/GAMMA

Where (If I understood it correctly) v is the input image and GAMMA is a constant.

And here's the code in MATLAB:

```
%%Fucnion de gamma
%%Entradas
%% I = imagen original
%% gamma = constante de gamma
%%Salidas 
%% G = imagen transformada

function [G] = FuncionGamma(I,gamma)
G=zeros(size(I));
for i=1: size(I, 1)
    for j=1: size(I, 2)
        G(i,j) = double(255 * (I(i,j)/255)).^(1/gamma);
    end
end
G=uint8(G); 
end
```

And here's the script to call it:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

gamma = 0.5;
gamma2 = 1.5;
I = imread("mantis.jpg");

[IMG1] = FuncionGamma(I,gamma); 
[IMG2] = FuncionGamma(I,gamma2); 

figure;
imshow(IMG1);

figure; 
imshow(IMG2);
```

Here are the results:

Original image:
[image]

Gamma = 0.5
[image: Gamma = 0.5]

And gamma = 1.5
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to your brackets:

```
G(i,j) = double(255 * (I(i,j)/255)).^(1/gamma);

G(i,j) = double( 255 * (I(i,j)/255) ) .^ (1/gamma);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The highlighted section is elevated to `1/gamma`. You need to place your brackets differently so that the power is computed first, then the multiplication. Note that `double` is not needed there, but you likely want to cast `I` to double before the division (dividing a `uint8` by a double produces a `uint8` in MATLAB).

Furthermore, you don't need to loop at all. MATLAB is good at processing whole matrices in one go. You can simplify your function to this:

```matlab
function G = FuncionGamma(I,gamma)
G = uint8( 255 * (double(I)/255).^(1/gamma) );
end
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you Cris. I also found out that I was only working with one channel (that's why the images appear on red).

Answer (score 0):

As I learned it in a course I took, you should scale the image before you do the mapping, at least for grayscale images. I'm not sure if it is needed with color images.

```
function imgGamma = GammaMap(img,gamma)
    imgTemp = double(img) % Create temporary image of type double
    imgTemp = 1./255      % Before mapping, scale the image: g = f*(1/255)
    img_temp = img_temp.^gamma; % Use the stretching formula
    imgGamma = img_temp.*255;   % After mapping, scale the image back, f = g*255
    imgGamma = uint8(imgGamma); % Before returning the image, transform it to uint8
end
```